# HABTM Paginate Sorting not working?

Tags: cakephp

I have a problem with Pagination and sorting in cake. I can sort using the first table but not if I try to sort using the second table.

I have the following tables (and the corresponding models):
users:  id, username
user_companies: id, user_id, company_id
company: id, name

So this is working just fine:

```
$this->User->find("all");
```

Pagiation is also working fine:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array('sort'=>'User.username');
$this->Paginator->paginate();
```

but if I try to sort by company name I get an error:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array('sort'=>'Company.name');
$this->Paginator->paginate();
```

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'Company.name' in 'order clause' SQL Query: SELECT `User`.`id`,
>   `User`.`email`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`role`,
>   `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified` FROM `cakeblog`.`users` AS `User`
>   WHERE 1 = 1 ORDER BY `Company`.`name` asc LIMIT 20

**Why is this not working?**

My User Model HABTM looks like this:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Company'=>array(
        'with'=>'UserCompanies'
        )
    );
```

and in Company:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'User' => array(
        'with' => 'UserCompanies',
        )
    );
```

---

The default query without sorting is:(are, because tehre are actually two queries):

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`role`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified` FROM `cakeblog`.`users` AS `User` WHERE 1 = 1 LIMIT 20
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT `Company`.`id`, `Company`.`name`, `CompaniesUser`.`id`, `CompaniesUser`.`user_id`, `CompaniesUser`.`company_id` FROM `cakeblog`.`companies` AS `Company` JOIN `cakeblog`.`companies_users` AS `CompaniesUser` ON (`CompaniesUser`.`user_id` IN (14, 16, 17) AND `CompaniesUser`.`company_id` = `Company`.`id`)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating two joins. Now it works like expected, I can sort using Company.name or any other field:

```
    $joins = array();
    $joins[] = array(
        'table'=>'companies_users',
        'alias'=>'CompanyUser',
        'type'=>'LEFT',
        'conditions'=>array(
            'CompanyUser.user_id = User.id'
            )
        );

    $joins[] = array(
        'table'=>'companies',
        'alias'=>'Company',
        'type'=>'LEFT',
        'conditions'=>array(
            'CompanyUser.company_id = Company.id')
        );

    $this->Paginator->settings = array('sort'=>'Company.name', 'joins'=>$joins);
    $x = $this->paginate();
    debug($x);
```